# Run a linux cmd for displaying installed applications with ownership details

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I have tried multiple commands to display a list of installed applications, but I want to know if there's a direct way to display all the installed applications along with the owners of the application.

Comment: use the package manager shipped with your distribution for that!

Comment: I thought of it too, but I am trying to run this command from Java! Therefore, I need to get the details in-order to manipulate it and display in a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force first approximation would be listing the files in your `PATH`:

```
for d in $(echo "$PATH" | tr : ' '); do ls -l "$d"; done
```

Comment: @Pravar Linux doesn't have bat, dll or exe files. Are you sure you are asking about Linux? What is your understanding of "application"? The programs in PATH **are** the applications and there's no other concept of ownership than the file ownership.

Comment: @Jens, thanks it worked! I am sorry, I need to clear my concepts!